# how to extract the machine code from the .text section of an ELF file?

Tags: c, assembly, x86, elf

let me explain a little more.
I am coding an x86 disassembler that takes as input an assembled program with ELF format. I have been able to extract the header and the array of sections from the file and print several dates such like  the name of the section, its size, etc. I am trying to extract the data that is stored in each section and print it in order to know that i actually have it, once i get it i will move onto the parsing and decoding stage but i dont managed to do it.
This is the code for the function that i have done so far.

```
void read_sections(FILE* fp,Elf32_Ehdr* elfhead, Elf32_Shdr* elf_shdr){


    // stand the FP pointer upon the beggining of the section header
    // and copy into the buffer  

    fseek(fp, elfhead->e_shoff,SEEK_SET);
    fread(elf_shdr,  sizeof(Elf32_Shdr), elfhead->e_shnum ,fp);

    // allocate the string table to cache the section names

    char* string_table;
    string_table = malloc( elf_shdr[elfhead->e_shstrndx].sh_size);

    fseek(fp,elf_shdr[elfhead->e_shstrndx].sh_offset,SEEK_SET);         // set the fp pointer upon the string table section
    fread(string_table,elf_shdr[elfhead->e_shstrndx].sh_size,1,fp);     // bring the table to memory 


    printf("========================\n");
    printf("************************\n");
    printf("READING SECTIONS\n" );
    printf("************************\n");
    printf("========================\n");


    unsigned int* instructions = NULL;

    for ( int i=0 ; i < elfhead->e_shnum ; i++){

        instructions = malloc (elf_shdr[i].sh_size );

        printf(" section name : %s\n",string_table + elf_shdr[i].sh_name);
        printf(" section type : %d\n", elf_shdr[i].sh_type );
        printf(" section size : %d\n",elf_shdr[i].sh_size );

        // read data from section 
        fseek(fp,elf_shdr[i].sh_offset,SEEK_SET);
        fread(instructions,elf_shdr[i].sh_size,1,fp);

        // find name 
        printf(" Dissasembly of section %s\n",string_table + elf_shdr[i].sh_name );


        for (unsigned int i = 0 ; i < elf_shdr[i].sh_size; i++){

            printf("%d\n", instructions[i]);
        }


        printf("\n");
        free(instructions);
    }

    free(string_table);
}
```

How to extract the machine code from the .text section of an ELF file?
If anyone can help i will be very thankfull!

Comment: The section header contains a file offset and a size. Just seek to that position and read it. Well, that seems to be what you are doing, so what is the problem?

Comment: the thing is that nothing appears on screen, i dont know actually why. all the other info is printed but not the code or the dates

Comment: I assume you dont want to use binutils you want to do this yourself?  the file format is quite simple as it appears you know.

Comment: @iluvian Is the section size greater than zero?  Also note that your loop is incorrect.  It should go to `elf_shdr[i].sh_size / sizeof(*instructions)` sind you dump `int` sized chunks of the instruction stream instead of bytes.

Comment: What about the program headers?  what is a dump of the number of headers and sizes and flags?

Comment: @fuz yes, the sections are all greater than 0 except the first one. I already correct that mistake on the loop, thank u for the observation.

Comment: Your loop is wrong  `for (unsigned int i = 0 ; i < elf_shdr[i].sh_size; i++){` you should use another variable, say `j`. As it is, your `i` is hiding the outer loop `i` and so `elf_shdr[i].sh_size` is not what you want.

Comment: @Jester yes! there it works THANK U, i can not believe i committed such a silly mistake, well that and the upper bound that was also wrong. thank u all. sorry for being such a noob, it is my first time writing somthing like this completely from scratch.